# How to extract KG figure from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data similar to the below that I need to easily separate from one cell so I can extract the packsize from.

- Dogfood A-2786-M 25KG/PAIL
- Catfood E6601 NS 200KG/DRUM
- Catfood SR9050 18.2KG/PAIL
- Dogfood BU 1000KG/IBC

The pack size can change and the product name can be different but is always a number followed by /PAIL, /DRUM or /IBC

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do this with a macro u can use this method: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

You can do it this way (see link for better explanation):

1. Click Data >Text to Columns
2. Click Delimited > Next
3. Just use *Space* and *Other* > `/` as delimiter
4. Click Next
5. Choose the format of the resulting cells
6. Select the cells you want to insert your splitted data

---

If you want to do this in a macro (excel-vba tag) then use the split function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx
First split with `/` as delimiter and just use the first entry in the resulting array to split for the *space* ( `" "` ). From that split you get the KGs as the last entry of the resulting array.

The syntax for using the split function your way is the following:

```
your_array = split(<your_string>, <delimiter>)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it shows the way and not the resulting code. Yet, I believe it would be even better if you were willing to recap and amend the content of the first link in your post. Link-only answers are not well perceived as the links may expire or move to a different location (rendering your answer useless).

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I will consider this for the future and edit my answer. @Ralph

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in A column then use this formula in B1 for A1 data and fill down.

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1)
```

Following image shows the results.
[image: Image showing sample and formula]

HTH

EDIT:

i Was not quite sure of your requrementsas to whether you want numeric figure or packing size. Anyway I was finding one formula quite complicated. If you can afford another helper column things are quite easy.

Use another formula in C1 and copy down .

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND("KG",TRIM(B1),1))
```

Screenshot of results is placed below. [image: Sample data to meet OP requirement]

It appeared to me while I was designing this formula that one single function may be too complicated. However I will look into possibilities of a single function.

Comment: Excellent formula this is what I'm looking for, is there a way to take off the /PAIL, /DRUM or /IBC as I only want the number in this instance.

Comment: @user6319689 additional formula in a helper column provided for you to get numeric figure as prima facie It appeared that a single formula will be too complicated.Please see the edit of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function GetKiloGrams(sIN As String) As Double
    arr = Split(sIN, " ")
    GetKiloGrams = 0
    For Each a In arr
        If InStr(1, a, "KG") > 0 Then
            brr = Split(a, "KG")
            GetKiloGrams = CDbl(brr(0))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

It parses the data and returns the proper value:

[image]